# How to retrieve group content if you are not a member (you are Global Administrator)?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, admin

I have a problem when trying to get whole content of the office 365 group. I am an Admin of my organisation and using msgraph to get content of the private group (where I am not a member of it). In the reply I got this message

> "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again., User '###' not
>   authorized to access group '@@@'. Reason: '(0xD10)'."

(content : group conversations). I found only one workaround to this problem - explicitly add admin as a member to the group and fetch everything you want. But it is not that I want to use (it is temporary solution). Can anybody provide me with more elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: What kind of content is it? Do you have a link to the graph documentation of your request? Maybe you an solve it by adding (and granting) application permissions to your application

Comment: I used this one [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get-conversation?view=graph-rest-1.0). What about app perms - everything configured properly (all perms checked, especially Group.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.All)

Comment: Even an admin cant who is not a member can't access contents of a private group.

Comment: @PavloMykhailyshyn did find another solution for this?

Comment: @Boomerang I did not find smth that could solve the problem I mentioned above. As I understand the only one possible and correct solution is to add an Admin as a member of a group.

Comment: I am stuck with the same problem...anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also faced the same issue. The only solution is to add the admin to the group as a member. While app permissions can indeed provide access to some attributes, it is not possible to access group email attachments through app permissions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http